# How to pass string with single quotations to in()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a query that I need to modify so that a string is passed to in(). The view table is being used by some other view table and ultimately by a stored procedure. The string values must be in ' '.

```
select region, county, name
from vw_main
where state - 'MD'
and building_id in ('101', '102') -- pass the string into in()
```

The values for the building_id will be entered at the stored procedure level upon its execution.

Comment: Use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

Comment: When you say "the view table is being used by some other view table" do you mean to say that you have nested views? This sounds so logical but is one of the worst things you can do from a performance perspective. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: I guess you're trying to create a `VIEW` with a parameter(s). That's not possible, instead you can [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for that.

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.   Another option would be to split or parse the delimited string, but we would need to know what version you are running

Comment: I would highly suggest you toss that string splitter you found in the bin. Using loops to split strings like that is going to suck the life out of your server. [Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) are several much better approaches. Of course, the best approach would be to use a table valued parameter instead of delimited strings.

Comment: ...or, on 2016 or better, STRING_SPLIT().

Comment: @AaronBertrand #truth I should have mentioned that myself. ;)

Comment: @AaronBertrand. Thanks! But I don't think the SQL Server version I am using is compatible to use the string_split() function....

Comment: @LucasC922 That's great, but it could be useful for other readers. You should get in the habit of actually telling us what version you're using as a part of asking your question. (There are tags for this purpose.)

Comment: @aaronBertrand. Sorry. I'm using the SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @LucasC922  where do the values you get for your "in" come from?  always user selected or can they be obtained by say looking at the logged in user's ID and only returning buildings associated to the company they work for?

Comment: @xQbert User selected/entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below scripts which will give you answer.

**Way 1**: Split CSV value using `XML` and directly use select query in where condition

```
DECLARE @StrBuildingIDs VARCHAR(1000)

SET @StrBuildingIDs = '101,102'

SELECT 
    vm.region, 
    vm.county, 
    vm.name
FROM vw_main vm
WHERE vm.state = 'MD'
AND vm.building_id IN
(
    SELECT
        l.value('.','VARCHAR(20)') AS Building_Id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@StrBuildingIDs,',','</a><a>') + '</a>') AS BuildIDXML
    ) x
    CROSS APPLY x.BuildIDXML.nodes('a') Split(l)
)
```

**Way 2**: Split CSV value using `XML`, Create Variable Table and use that in where condition

```
DECLARE @StrBuildingIDs VARCHAR(1000)

SET @StrBuildingIDs = '101,102'

DECLARE @TblBuildingID TABLE(BuildingId INT)

INSERT INTO @TblBuildingID(BuildingId)
SELECT
    l.value('.','VARCHAR(20)') AS Building_Id
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@StrBuildingIDs,',','</a><a>') + '</a>') AS BuildIDXML
) x
CROSS APPLY x.BuildIDXML.nodes('a') Split(l)

SELECT 
    vm.region, 
    vm.county, 
    vm.name
FROM vw_main AS vm
WHERE vm.state = 'MD'
AND vm.building_id IN
(
    SELECT
        BuildingId
    FROM @TblBuildingID
)
```

**Way 3**: Split CSV value using `XML`, Create Variable Table and use that in INNER JOIN

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the input string is *not* end-user input, you can do this.  That is, derived or pulled from another table or other controlled source.

```
DECLARE @in nvarchar(some length) = N'''a'',''b'',''c'''
declare @stmt nvarchar(4000) = N'
select region, county, name
from vw_main
where state = ''MD''
and building_id in ({instr})'

set @stmt = replace(@stmt, N'{instr}', @instr)
exec sp_executesql @stmt=@stmt;
```

If the input *is* from an end-user, this is safer:

```
declare @ table (a int, b char)
insert into @(a, b) values (1,'A'), (2, 'B')
declare @str varchar(50) = 'A,B'

select t.* from @ t
join (select * from string_split(@str, ',')) s(b)
on t.b = s.b
```

You may like it better anyway, since there's no dynamic sql involved.  However you must be running SQL Server 2016 or higher.

Comment: This is a terrible approach to this problem. This is wide open to sql injection. You should never ever ever receive a parameter, build that parameter value into a string an execute it.